# Six questions limit per 24 hour

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, rate-limiting

How can I know if I had posted 6 questions previously when would my 24 hour limit gets over for posting more questions?

Edit: I had posted 6 questions, after few moments(within 5min) I found 2 questions among them as duplicate, so I deleted it. But still I have the 6 question limit though number of questions are 4.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak- What is that $rate-limiting$ tag? It's a good or bad thing for me?

Comment: On your profile page, click `questions`, sort by `newest`, then click the 6th most recent question to find when you posted it. // The tag `rate-limiting` describes what your question is about. It is an informational tag, neither good nor bad.

Comment: Re: edit. This is not a bug. Deleted questions count toward the limit, *by design*. It is advisable to look for duplicates *before* posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throttles reset 24 hours after the first post (generally speaking), not at a particular hour or anything.

It is also completely by-design, any post is counted regardless of whether it's deleted or not.