# What is the standard time maintained by MSE?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

I get this message "You can only post 6 questions in a 24 hour period". So, I would like to know the standard time maintained by MSE so that I know when I can again ask questions.

I would also like to know why there is a limit for the number of questions that can be asked?

Comment: re: the addition.  There are daily (and monthly) limits on the number of questions individual users can ask because the system is designed to [optimize for pearls not sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).  If users had unlimited questions there would be no incentive to think about the questions being asked; with a limit questions become somewhat scarce, and users should take more care in their use.  [This MSO answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127569/214632) likely says it better than I can.

Comment: Ohhh...then that's a very wise decision by the community(moderators).

Answer (score 14):

I believe it's a rolling limit; it doesn't depend on any particular time zone.  You can only post 6 questions in *any* 24-hour period.  In particular, you can ask a question again 24 hours after the time you asked your 6th-most-recent question.

See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7078/68107): "Throttles reset 24 hours after the first post (generally speaking), not at a particular hour or anything."

Note, however, that if you continue asking 6 questions in every 24-hour period you will hit the other limit, which is that you can only ask 50 questions in any period of 30 days.  So be careful, and try thinking about your questions more before posting too many of them.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the standard time maintained by MSE?

The current server time can be found here:

[image]