# Reaching question limit problem

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting, post-ban

Recently I would like to ask a question but it showed up "I've reached the question limit", what should I do to remove my ban?

Comment: Have a look at the previous questions on this topic, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-ban I'm sure you'll find an answer. But what does your question here have to do with the title you have given it?

Comment: I think the message about "question limit" is different from a "ban"?  There is a limit of a certain number of questinos per day that can be asked.  And perhaps an additional limit of a certain number of questions per week.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7077/442

Comment: 00xxqhxx00: If you look at the above comments, it seems that your question needs to be clarified a bit. I have added both ([meta-tag:post-ban]) and ([meta-tag:rate-limiting]) to the tags - it seems quite likely that you mean one or the other, when you clarify to question you should also edit the tags accordingly.

Comment: I suspect you may have deleted more than one of your recent Questions.  While I cannot see these, there are no Questions from the last 30 days visible on your (main) Math.SE user page.  (Also you earned the Peer Pressure badge back in April, so you must have deleted at least one downvoted post in the past.)  Deleting posts will not help you avoid rate limits.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30411/why-have-i-been-banned-from-asking-questions?r=SearchResults&s=6|34.1647

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), you should start by improving your existing questions. This means that you should try to make your questions as clear and specific as possible. However, if you are unable to improve your existing questions, you are given a chance to ask a new one about half a year later, before you are banned again from asking questions. However, if the question is good enough, you might get unbanned and you can continue asking questions. Hope this helped.

Comment: The OP should know that when you delete poorly received questions you've asked, they are not longer readily available for you to edit and improve.